# If the Textbox is null this code returns date 1-1-0001 ... I want it to return null or empty string so what can I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

```
DateTime fromDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(FromDateTextBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fromDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the return values of TryParseExact

```
bool res = DateTime.TryParseExact(FromDateTextBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fromDate);
if (res == false)
{
    //date is not parsable...
}
```